# Read data with missing values with Python into arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a datafile which is similar to (The original file is much bigger),

```
Data
6 6
0.0 0.2 0.4
0.6 0.8
1.0
0.0 0.4 0.6
1.2 1.6
2.0
1.0 3.0 4.0 1.0
1.0 3.0
1.0 2.0 1.0 4.0
5.0 2.0
3.0 3.0 1.0 1.0
5.0 1.0
2.0 7.0 1.0 1.0
5.0 2.0
2.0 3.0 8.0 6.0
3.0 1.0
3.0 3.0 4.0 6.0
1.0 1.0
```

and I need to plot it as a 2D contour.
The first line is dummy, The first 6 shows the number of elements in the x direction as

```
0.0 0.2 0.4
0.6 0.8
1.0
```

and the second one shows the number of elements in the y direction as,

```
0.0 0.4 0.6
1.2 1.6
2.0
```

Then each 6 number shows the value of contour in each row, starting from row 1 as,

```
1.0 3.0 4.0 1.0
1.0 3.0
```

I want to cast this data into a 2D array so that I can plot them.
I tried,

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('fileHere',delimiter= " ",skip_header=1)
```

to read data into a general array and then split it. But I get the following error,

```
Line #16999 (got 15 columns instead of 3)
```

I also tried the readline() and split() functions of Python but they make it much harder to continue. I want to have x and y in arrays and a separate array for the data in a let's say 6X6 shape. In Matlab I used to use the fscanf function

```
fscanf(fid,'%d',6);
```

I will be happy to have your ideas on this. Thanks

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read the full file into a variable, then replace all newline `'\n'`, then split and convert it into an ndarray.

Here's how I did it.

```
import numpy as np
txt = '''\
6 6
0.0 0.2 0.4
0.6 0.8
1.0
0.0 0.4 0.6
1.2 1.6
2.0
1.0 3.0 4.0 1.0
1.0 3.0
1.0 2.0 1.0 4.0
5.0 2.0
3.0 3.0 1.0 1.0
5.0 1.0
2.0 7.0 1.0 1.0
5.0 2.0
2.0 3.0 8.0 6.0
3.0 1.0
3.0 3.0 4.0 6.0
1.0 1.0'''

txt_list = txt.replace('\n',' ').split()

# if you want to convert the values to floats, you can include the next line
# otherwise the data will be converted to numpy as string
txt_list = [float(i) for i in txt_list]

width = int(txt_list[1])
height = len(txt_list[2:])//width
txt_array = np.reshape(txt_list[2:], (height, width))
print (txt_array)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[['0.0' '0.2' '0.4' '0.6' '0.8' '1.0']
 ['0.0' '0.4' '0.6' '1.2' '1.6' '2.0']
 ['1.0' '3.0' '4.0' '1.0' '1.0' '3.0']
 ['1.0' '2.0' '1.0' '4.0' '5.0' '2.0']
 ['3.0' '3.0' '1.0' '1.0' '5.0' '1.0']
 ['2.0' '7.0' '1.0' '1.0' '5.0' '2.0']
 ['2.0' '3.0' '8.0' '6.0' '3.0' '1.0']
 ['3.0' '3.0' '4.0' '6.0' '1.0' '1.0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a smart solution to reformat your input is possible using
*Pandas*.

Start with reading your input file as a *pandasonic* DataFrame (with
standard field separator, i.e. a comma):

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.txt')
```

As your input file does not contain commas, each line is read as a **single**
field and the column name (*Data*) is taken from the first line.

So far the initial part of *df* is:

```
          Data
0          6 6
1  0.0 0.2 0.4
2      0.6 0.8
3          1.0
4  0.0 0.4 0.6
```

The left column is the index, but it is not important.
The type of the only column is *object*, actually a *string*.

Then, to reformat this DataFrame into a 6-columns *Numpy* array, it
is enough to run the following one-liner:

```
result = df.drop(0).Data.str.split(' ').explode().astype('float').values.reshape(-1, 6)
```

Steps:

- `drop(0)` - Drop the initial row (with index *0*).
- `Data` - Take *Data* column.
- `str.split(' ')` - Split each element on spaces (the result is a list of strings).
- `explode()` - Convert each list into a sequence of rows. So far each
  element is of *string* type.
- `astype('float')` - Change the type to *float*.
- `values` - Take the underlying *Numpy* (1-D) array.
- `reshape(-1, 6)` - Reshape to 6 columns and as many rows as needed.

The result, for your data sample is:

```
array([[0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.4, 0.6, 1.2, 1.6, 2. ],
       [1. , 3. , 4. , 1. , 1. , 3. ],
       [1. , 2. , 1. , 4. , 5. , 2. ],
       [3. , 3. , 1. , 1. , 5. , 1. ],
       [2. , 7. , 1. , 1. , 5. , 2. ],
       [2. , 3. , 8. , 6. , 3. , 1. ],
       [3. , 3. , 4. , 6. , 1. , 1. ]])
```

And the last step is to divide this array into:

- 2 initial rows (*x* and *y* coordinates),
- following rows (actual data),

To do it, run:

```
x = result[0]
y = result[1]
data = result[2:]
```

Alternative: Don't create separate variables, but call *plt.contour*
passing respective rows of *result* as *X*, *Y* and *Z*.
Something like:

```
plt.contour(result[0], result[1], result[2:]);
```

Comment: specifying the `sep` parameter in `read_csv` or using `read_fwf` allow you to skip a few steps

Comment: The provided data sample contains initial row with 2 fields **1 char wide**.
But further rows have fields **3 chars wide**.
I'm also afraid that further (not presented) rows can contain values > 10.0,
so even the size of these fields can be varying.
Conclusion: *read_fwf* is not any good choice.
Using *read_csv* with *sep=' '* in also not a good concept, since we want
to "glue together" sequences of 6 input numbers.